# Moving all git content with complete history one-level up in the folder hierarchy

Tags: git

My git-Repo currently looks like this:

```
.git\
A_Dir\
+---- B_Dir\
+---- C_Dir\
+---- ManyFiles
```

I'd like to move all the contents of `A_Dir` up one level (and remove `A_Dir`) like this [including the whole history, refs, tags - as if the contents of `A_Dir` had always been on the same dir-level of `.git` so that i'll be able to merge all the branches - as the move never happened]:

```
.git\
B_Dir\
C_Dir\
ManyFiles
```

I've already found some answers on stackoverflow like:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git ls-files -s |
    sed "s-\t\"*-&new_subdir/-" |
    GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new git update-index --index-info && 
    mv $GIT_INDEX_FILE.new $GIT_INDEX_FILE' --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

this rewrites the whole history but moves the contents up in the `new_subdir` directory. I actually need the command that does the inverse!

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git filter-branch` has explicit support for what you want via its `--subdirectory-filter` option:

```
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter A_Dir --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Any history for content outside of `A_Dir` will be lost. This will also rewrite any tags to point to the modified commits thanks to the `--tag-name-filter` option.